# Why is the 'mouseup' event not fired in google maps on IE for a div added to the overlayMouseTarget layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm adding a custom overlay to a google map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

As part of this I want users to be able to click on the overlay. To that end I've added a transparent and empty div to the "overlayMouseTarget" layer which should be the right place to capture such events.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#initialize

I want users to be able to click the overlay, but I want to ignore a user trying to drag the overlay. To achieve this I can't just use the 'click' event, I have to listen to 'mousedown', 'mousedrag', and 'mouseup'. And with a few flags to track state it should work great!

What I'm finding is that in chrome/firefox/edge/etc it works okay, but in IE the mouseup event is never fired.

Here's a JS fiddle based on googles sample code with the extra div and event handlers that reproduces the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mmx78jrx/17/

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 62.323907,
      lng: -150.109291
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
    new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' +
    'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}

function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

  this.bounds_ = bounds;
  this.image_ = image;
  this.map_ = map;

  this.div_ = null;  
  this.mouseDiv_ = null;

  this.setMap(map);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.appendChild(img);

  this.div_ = div;

  var mouseDiv = document.createElement('div');
  mouseDiv.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  mouseDiv.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  mouseDiv.style.position = 'absolute';

  this.mouseDiv_ = mouseDiv;

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(mouseDiv);

  mouseDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    console.log("mousedown");
  });

  mouseDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", function (event) {
    console.log("mouseup");
  });
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';

  var mouseDiv = this.mouseDiv_;
  mouseDiv.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  mouseDiv.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  mouseDiv.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  mouseDiv.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
  this.div_ = null;

  this.mouseDiv_.parentNode.removeChild(this.mouseDiv_);
  this.mouseDiv_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Open it up in a browser that's not IE, hit F12 to bring up the devtools, switch to the console log and then click the overlay and you should see:

```
mousedown
mouseup
```

Now do the same in IE and you should see only:

```
mousedown
```

If I add event.preventDefault() in the mousedown then I do get the mouseup event in IE! http://jsfiddle.net/mmx78jrx/18/

```
mouseDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
    console.log("mousedown");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But that prevents the map from scrolling during a drag (not click) event.
In the original example you can click on the overlay, drag and the map will move, where as with the "fix" this behaviour is disabled.

Unfortunately google don't provide an un-minified version of the maps script, so I can't see how they themselves are working around this issue with objects such as the Marker.